# JWT "invalid_grant" in Signature in Google OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I am writing some code to try to get a token to use from Google in OAuth2.  This is for a service account, so the instructions are here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I keep getting this error when I post the JWT to Google:

> { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature." }

Here is the code:

```
try{        
    var nowInSeconds : Number = (Date.now() / 1000);
    nowInSeconds = Math.round(nowInSeconds);
    var fiftyNineMinutesFromNowInSeconds : Number = nowInSeconds + (59 * 60);
    
    
    var claimSet : Object = {};
    claimSet.iss   = "{{RemovedForPrivacy}}";        
    claimSet.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage";
    claimSet.aud   = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    claimSet.iat   = nowInSeconds; 
    claimSet.exp   = fiftyNineMinutesFromNowInSeconds;
    
    var header : Object = {};
    header.alg = "RS256";
    header.typ = "JWT";
    
    /* Stringify These */
    var claimSetString = JSON.stringify(claimSet);
    var headerString = JSON.stringify(header);
    
    /* Base64 Encode These */
    var claimSetBaseSixtyFour = StringUtils.encodeBase64(claimSetString);
    var headerBaseSixtyFour = StringUtils.encodeBase64(headerString);
    
    var privateKey = "{{RemovedForPrivacy}}";
    
    /* Create the signature */
    var signature : Signature = Signature();
    signature =  signature.sign(headerBaseSixtyFour + "." + claimSetBaseSixtyFour, privateKey , "SHA256withRSA");
    
    /* Concatenate the whole JWT */
    var JWT = headerBaseSixtyFour + "." + claimSetBaseSixtyFour + "." + signature;
    
    /* Set Grant Type */
    var grantType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
    
    /* Create and encode the body of the token post request */
    var assertions : String = "grant_type=" + dw.crypto.Encoding.toURI(grantType) + "&assertion=" + dw.crypto.Encoding.toURI(JWT);
    
    /* Connect to Google And Ask for Token */
    /* TODO Upload Certs? */
    var httpClient : HTTPClient = new HTTPClient();
    httpClient.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    httpClient.timeout = 30000;
    httpClient.open('POST', "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
    httpClient.send(assertions);
  
    if (httpClient.statusCode == 200) {
       //nothing
    } else {
       pdict.errorMessage = httpClient.errorText;
    }  
    
}
catch(e){
    Logger.error("The error with the OAuth Token Generator is --> " + e);
}
```

Does anyone know why the JWT is failing?

Comment: Check if your service account private key is still valid from cloud console

Comment: Is that Typescript? Could you tag the question with the language used?

Comment: @Brad    Have you found a solution?

Comment: Looking for a solution here. Getting same thing.

Answer (score 12):

The problem might be related to the fact that your `StringUtils.encodeBase64()` method is likely to perform a standard base64 encoding.

According to the [JWT spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jones-json-web-token-10), however, it's not the standard base64 encoding that needs to be used, but the [the URL- and filename-safe Base64 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5), with the `=` padding characters omitted.

If you don't have a utility method handy for base64URL encoding, you can verify by

- replacing all `+` with `-`;
- replacing all `/` with `_`;
- removing all `=`

in your base64-encoded strings.

Also, is your signature also base64-encoded? It needs to be, following the same rules as described above.

Comment: Robby,

This is super helpful.  Quick question... the key that I download from Google looks something like this....

    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n{Bunch of stuff removed}=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n

Do I remove any of the following before I use the key to sign?

"\n" or "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" or the "=" before "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

Comment: Should not have to.

Comment: Thank you sir. That was exactly my problem. I was able to use  `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString` from commons-codec.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before and this is what was wrong:

- wrong application name (project ID)
- wrong service account ID (email)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error could be "Your service account is not activated". With `gsutil` installed from the Cloud SDK, you should authenticate with service account credentials.

1- Use an existing service account or create a new one, and download the associated private key.

2- Use `gcloud auth activate-service-account` to authenticate with the service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file [KEY_FILE]
```

Where `[KEY_FILE]` is the name of the file that contains your service account credentials.

Link for more detail: [Activate service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts)

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if a developer mistakenly copies, edits, and uses a service account key file for a purpose other than the one for which the file was originally intended. For example:

1. Developer A creates SA 1
2. Developer A uses `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ...` to create the secret file for SA 1, encrypts it, and checks it in to source control
3. Developer B creates SA 2
4. Developer B (mistakenly) decrypts and copies the secret file from step 2, modifies some of its fields with data from SA 2, then attempts to use it in an application

The resolution in this scenario obviously is for Developer B to get rid of the copied/edited file and create a new secret file with gcloud like Developer A did in step 2.

Comment: yes that is right @Logan May, and copy pasting the contents of the json file can also be a problem. Better use the downloaded json file directly,  if using a key file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error occur when using a service account. I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I came back to it the next day and it worked. So maybe Google Cloud takes some time to propagate every once in a while.